# How to get a windows azure table entity on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, entity, azure-table-storage

I want to query a table on the cloud and retreive a entity based on its partition key. How can I do this on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

Table storage is accessible from outside the cloud. So the accurate, but maybe not helpful, answer is: the same way you would access it from anywhere else.

But you may also want to look at the [Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://watwp.codeplex.com/). They also have some extensive [documentation](http://watwp.codeplex.com/documentation), which includes a section on working with tables.